# displaying products in jsp as a grid

Tags: html, jsp, while-loop, grid

i'm trying to display my database content on a grid like this one:

[grid example](http://www.zen-cart.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=11996&d=1361832195)

I'm getting all products on one vertical colmun like this:

[my products display](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/217118impri.png)

products are inserted in the array"Arrayp" ,right now i can diplay database content on vertical table or horizontal table but not on a grid like mentioned, this is my code and i would appreciate a help

```
<TABLE  > 
<%  
while (cmp<=size ) 
{ 
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td>");

out.println("<p><img src=\"images/" + Arrayp.get(cmi) + " \" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></p>");
out.println("<p> categorie " + Arrayp.get(cmp) + "</p>");  
out.println("<p> prix  "  + Arrayp.get(cmpri) + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>quantité disponible " + Arrayp.get(cmpqt) + "</p>"); 
out.println("<form name='f' action='panier' method='post'>");
out.println("<input type='hidden' value= "+Arrayp.get(cmbref) +" name='ref' >");
out.println("<p>quantité desirée</p>");
out.println("<p><input type='text' name='nbr' ></p>");
out.println("<input type='submit' value='ajouter au panier' />") ;
out.println ("</form>");




cmp=cmp+8;
cmi=cmi+8;
cmpqt=cmpqt+8;
cmbref=cmbref+8;
out.println("<p></p>");
out.println("<p></p>");



out.println("</td>");
out.println("<tr>");
%>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: why you hard coding html's using java code?? use [jstl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Comment: yes i know but this is not the problem ,the problem is that i can't get a grid display like mentioned on the image

Comment: what you getting add image of your page to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `counter` to count `items` and when 4 item crossed add a new `<tr>` tag. Where now you adding `<tr>` tag for each `item`. Below i have give example, you can modify as you need.

Like:

```
<html>
<head>
tr {
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <%
     int start = 0;
     int elementsLen = 10;
     int counter = 1;
     int noOfItemsInRow = 4; //set number of td you want in tr
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     noOfItemsInRow++;

     //start table
     out.println("<table>");
     while(start<=elementsLen){ 
        sb.append("<td>");
        sb.append(start);
        sb.append("</td>");

        //check if noOfElemntsInRow elements is reached keep it in a new row
        if(++counter==noOfItemsInRow){
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println(sb.toString());
            out.println("</tr>");
            sb.setLength(0);
            counter = 1;
        }
        start++;
     }
    //print remaining td elements in a new row
     if(sb.length()>1){
         out.println("<tr>");
         out.println(sb.toString());
         out.println("</tr>");
     }
    //close table
     out.println("</table>");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output format]

**Note:** this is not a good idea to use scriptlets in jsp, instead you should use jstl.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now , i tried before with the if and it didnt work properly.
bizarrely i tried it today without closing the tr  i mean without /tr in the end and it works and i got a clean grid :D
update : the problem was solved by closing the TR outside of the while loop, thx to all
here is the working code

```
 int c =0;
      int numberofcolumns=4;
      %>

    <TABLE> 

    <%  
    while (cmp<=size ) 
    { 
    c++;

    if (c==numberofcolumns){
        numberofcolumns=numberofcolumns+3;
    out.println("<tr>");
    }
    out.println("<td>");

    out.println("<p><img src=\"images/" + Arrayp.get(cmi) + " \" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></p>");
    out.println("<p> categorie " + Arrayp.get(cmp) + "</p>");  
    out.println("<p> prix  "  + Arrayp.get(cmpri) + "</p>"); 
    out.println("<p>quantité disponible " + Arrayp.get(cmpqt) + "</p>"); 
    out.println("<form name='f' action='panier' method='post'>");
    out.println("<input type='hidden' value= "+Arrayp.get(cmbref) +" name='ref' >");
    out.println("<p>quantité desirée</p>");
    out.println("<p><input type='text' name='nbr' ></p>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='ajouter au panier' />") ;
    out.println ("</form>");


    out.println("<td>");

    cmp=cmp+8;
    cmi=cmi+8;
    cmpqt=cmpqt+8;
    cmbref=cmbref+8;
    out.println("<p></p>");
    out.println("<p></p>");





    }//
   out.println("</tr>");
    %>
    </TABLE>
```